# Creating Build file for Jar - Java 6

Tags: java, jar, antbuilder

I'm make my program as .jar file and giving it to the user. In case of any update in any program file, I need to provide the user with Ant build file.

So, is it enough if I provide the AntBuild file, created via Export-> General ->Ant buildFiles? Or Do i need to make any changes in that file?

Comment: If you distribute your application as JAR file. Why not deliver the updated application the same way?

Comment: We upload the files to a version controller, from where the files are taken, build and jar file is created. So, the person in between who makes the jar and wants this build file.

Comment: Sorry don't get it what you want to do. What's a "version controller"? Do you mean a source code versioning system? If so, why not adding the build script to the source code versioning?

Comment: The 'build script' you refer is the 'Ant  build' created using eclipse?

Comment: Yes, I mean. The script which you use to compile your code and to create the JAR file.